# Weird systemctl behavior

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, systemctl

I installed Postgres9.6 on my Ubuntu 16.04 through `apt-get`.  and I installed the same version on an AWS ubuntu instance to try replication.

I was following the steps from this blog:
http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2013/02/16/zero-to-postgresql-streaming-replication-in-10-mins/

Now I can log to the postgres user on both machines, and run psql and execute all database operations. But when I check the status of the server (on both machines) using `sudo systemctl status postgres.service`, I get this:

> ● postgres.service    Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or
>   directory)    Active: inactive (dead)

Which is weird because I can run `psql`, right?
And this prevents me from creating remote connections.

Comment: "And this prevents me" --- totally not "this". If you can `psql` - then the daemon is running. You cannot make remote connections because of something else: firewall, pg_hba, etc...

Comment: @zerkms but why does it show the server status to be inactive(dead)

Comment: You're getting "file not found" on both machines?  That sounds like a bug in the systemd service file for the PostgreSQL package.  Did you install it from Ubuntu, or from the PostgreSQL Debs repository?

Comment: @FuzzyChef from the Postgres Repo 
I followed the steps in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/831293/666490

Comment: please rename it to weird systemctl  behaviour - error seem to have nothing to do with postgres

Comment: renamed it to systemctl

Comment: I'm not going to have time to spin up an Ubuntu vm to check this this week.  Hopefully someone else has one around to test.